# Laravel 7: External link not working in localhost

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

The external links of CSS and JS are not working when I try access my Laravel project from localhost by `www.localhost/myproject` this. But others porject run well. I have to run `php artisan serve` command to run my project perfectly. When I upload it to Cpanel hosting it shows the error `This site can’t be reached`.
This is the app URL in env file `APP_URL=http://localhost`

This is how I declare the links `{{ asset('backend/mystyle.css') }}`
All of my CSS, Js files are under public folder. I think there might some problem in .htaccesss.

File structure:

```
-app
-public
  --backend
  --css
  --robots.txt
  --web.config
-.env
-.htaccess
-index.php
-server.php
```

.htaccess file

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteBase /hrm-payroll-v3-2021/
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php70 .php
   <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
     suPHP_ConfigPath /opt/php70/lib
   </IfModule>
```

Index.php file

```
<?php
 define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true)); 
 require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
 $app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
 $kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

 $response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
 );

 $response->send();

 $kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Server.php file

```
$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/index.php';
```

Can you please tell me why this problem may occur? What is the possible solution to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: You need to change your APP_URL to something else.  Localhost is inaccessible to external traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve my problem with updating htaccess file.

htaccess file:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
Options -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
RewriteRule ^(css|js|images|trainer-cv)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
```

then rename the server.php file to index.php

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your APP_URL to your domain

Comment: I tried with that. In localhost it doesn't show the CSS, JS and in Cpanel it shows error. I have updated the URL correctly for localhost and Cpanel

Comment: about css and js you need to check path is correct? its should be read files from folder of project

Comment: All my CSS and JS files are in the root folder. But when I run the project with the serve command it searches in the public folder. Can you please check the htaccess file and update it which will correctly remove public from the URL

Comment: you need go to “File Manager”.  then in public_html and there upload your js ,css,....there all file should go there in this folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you run `php artisan serve` without any arguments, Laravel starts a local web server on port `8000`. Therefore you should consider this in your `.env` file by adding the port number in your `APP_URL`.

When you upload your project to a cpanel, make sure the web server is referring to `YourProject\public` as document-root directory.

Comment: I have updated the question. I removed the public from URL.